# Coefficient plot of two regressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I am trying to create a coefficient plot using `ggplot` that combines the results of two different regressions. The coefficients, standard errors and confidence interval bounds of each regression are stored as a data frame of the form:

```
## regression1: 
   var     betas       crse       upper       lower
1  x1  0.517251974 0.58176862  0.37751553  0.05698842
2  x2 -0.260210445 0.03521915 -0.12118217 -0.25923872
3  x3  0.680752318 0.08844444  0.75410023  0.40740441
4  x4  0.663395004 0.05090350  0.26316403  0.06362598
5  x5 -0.551992451 0.03289870 -0.08751219 -0.21647271

## regression2:
   var     betas       crse       upper       lower
1  x1 -0.343254719 0.05498965  0.01451302 -0.20104246
2  x2  0.126434568 0.02243139  0.17040108  0.08247165
3  x3 -0.178460203 0.06215729 -0.05663415 -0.30028625
4  x4  0.301058265 0.03737595  0.37431378  0.22780275
5  x5 -0.054594805 0.02037967 -0.01465139 -0.09453822
```

My approach was to combine both regressions into one data frame using:

```r
combined <- rbind(regression1, regression2)
```

And then I use `ggplot`:

```r
ggplot(combined, aes(x=var, y=betas)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=var, y=betas), 
             color="red", 
             shape=15) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), 
                width=.25, 
                size=.65)
```

However, the lines of the two models with the coefficient / confidence intervals overlap each other in the plot and it is not easy to distinguish which one is which. Is there a way to separate the lines so that they can be distinguished? Perhaps I am using the wrong approach and I should not `rbind` the two plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2602640's answer gets the essential points but there are a couple of additional shortcuts you can use.

- `dplyr::bind_rows()` will automatically set up an "id" column (you need to name the arguments, which is a little annoying; otherwise the id reverts to numeric indices)
- if you're OK with lines without end caps for your error bars (recommended by the minimalist/Tufte school of quantitative graphics anyway) then `geom_pointrange()` will do both the points and the CIs at the same time (perhaps there's an analogous combined-points-and-errorbars geom out there somewhere in the extended ggplot-verse?)
- you may be interested in the `broom` and `dotwhisker` packages, which can further streamline similar tasks (e.g. if you have two regressions `dotwhisker::dwplot(r1, r2)` will automatically construct the combined coefficient plot)

The chosen width (0.25) for `position_dodge()` is an aesthetic choice you may want to adjust (ggplot dodges geoms like boxplots automatically, but considers points zero-width, so you need to specify an amount of displacement)

```r
library(tidyverse)
combined <- bind_rows(reg1=reg1, reg2=reg2, .id="model")
ggplot(combined, aes(x=var, y=betas, ymin=lower, ymax=upper, colour=model)) +
   geom_pointrange(position=position_dodge(width=0.25))
```

### data setup

```r
reg1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   var     betas       crse       upper       lower
 x1  0.517251974 0.58176862  0.37751553  0.05698842
 x2 -0.260210445 0.03521915 -0.12118217 -0.25923872
 x3  0.680752318 0.08844444  0.75410023  0.40740441
 x4  0.663395004 0.05090350  0.26316403  0.06362598
 x5 -0.551992451 0.03289870 -0.08751219 -0.21647271
")

reg2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   var     betas       crse       upper       lower
 x1 -0.343254719 0.05498965  0.01451302 -0.20104246
 x2  0.126434568 0.02243139  0.17040108  0.08247165
 x3 -0.178460203 0.06215729 -0.05663415 -0.30028625
 x4  0.301058265 0.03737595  0.37431378  0.22780275
 x5 -0.054594805 0.02037967 -0.01465139 -0.09453822
")
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a new variable to track the two regressions and allow the colour of the points / errorbars change with that variable. The dodging allows to separate the two regressions sideways. So:

```
regression1$Reg <- "Regression 1"
regression2$Reg <- "Regression 2"

combined <- rbind(regression1, regression2)

ggplot(combined, aes(x=var, y=betas)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=var, y=betas, colour = Reg), 
             shape=15, position = position_dodge(width = 0.25)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, colour = Reg), 
                width=.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), 
                size=.65)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly, thank you so much! I also added "shape = Reg" after colour to change the shape of each datapoint (in greyscale) and it works perfectly. However for some reason the coefficients are not in the order above (i.e. they are ordered x3, x2, x5, x1, x4), is there a reason for that? And is it possible to change the ordering manually? Thank you very much again!

Comment: Strange, but you can definitely handle that using factor levels. So: `combined$var <- factor(combined$var, levels = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"))`. This should force ggplot to plot in order (even though it should've anyway...)

Comment: If this worked for you and you prefer the `ggplot` approach to `matplot`, please consider accepting my or Ben Bolker's answer (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer). If you prefer `matplot`, please accept the second answer...

Answer (score 2):

You may use `matplot`. However, your regression seems to be flawed, since betas don't lie between the CI's.

```
matplot(regression1[, c(2, 4:5)], type='l', lty=c(1, 2, 2), col=1)
matlines(regression2[, c(2, 4:5)], type='l', lty=c(1, 2, 2), col=2)
legend('topright', legend=paste('r', 1:2), text.col=1:2, bty='n')
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed the numbers were wonky (but figured that was just something messed up in transcription etc.)

Comment: Apologies for the transcription typo you are right, I will also try this method thank you very much!